# Implementing 'Update' functionality

Tags: windows-installer

I want to implement the 'Update' functionality for one of my .NET application. I saw that the 'Advanced Installer' contains this functionality.

Anybody recommends Advanced Installer for updating my app?

Also I'd like to know if this can be done using Visual Studio Setup project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a ClickOnce install then update will be an automatic feature, depending on how you've setup ClickOnce. For more details on ClickOnce see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28VS.80%29.aspx). Unfortunately I do not think that the Visual Studio Setup project has such a feature. If you need an installer with update/patch functionality then I would recommend looking at [WiX 3](http://wix.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I want to avoid ClickOnce. WiX 3 seems interesting.